# Set a forms element based on record updating in mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a PHP script that loads the users records that are in the MYSQL Database Table.

This database table contains others reviews from the site as it is simply a reviews table.

Each review or entry receives it's very own Unique ID.

Once the user has loaded his/her reviews. I have a button on the table on the loaded page that allows them to update that specific record.

Somehow I am needing to be able to pass the Unique ID from the mysql database (maybe through the button?) and place that into a hidden field on the form.

The form will then submit when the user clicks submit and update the record that is associated with that unique id and no other records.

I have tried for hours on end trying to figure out a logical solution to this problem with no success (obviously). I hope that this is specific enough on what I am needing and any help/suggestions will be appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my code:

**This is the php script that loads the reviews on the page.**

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments
        WHERE email='$_SESSION[email]' ORDER BY dt");

echo "<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' border='1' width='auto'>
    <tr>
    <td colspan='5' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center;'>The Green Panda</td> 
                                                  </tr>
<tr>                                                                   <td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #96b759; color: white;'>Date</td>
                                                <td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #96b759; color: white;'>Email</td>
                                                <td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #96b759; color: white;'>Review</td>
                                                <td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #96b759; color: white;'>Update</td>
                                            </tr>";

                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                  {
                                      echo "<tr>";
                                      echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #758F45; color: white;'>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
                                      echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #758F45; color: white;'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                                      echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #758F45; color: white;'>" . $row['body'] . "</td>";
                                      echo "<td colspan='2' style='padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 10px; border:1px solid black; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; background-color: #758F45; color: white;'><input type='button' value='Update' onclick='showDiv()'/></td>";
                                      echo "</tr>";
                                  }
                                      echo "</table>";
                                ?>
```

**This the the html form**

```
<div id="update-form"> 

                                    <form method="post" action="update.php">

                                        <label>Your Review:</label> 
                                        <input type="text" name="body">

                                        <input type="text" name="id" value="" readonly>

                                        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="hideDiv()"> 

                                    </form>

                                </div>
```

**This is the PHP script that processes the update (external script)**

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE comments SET body= '$_POST[body]'
  WHERE id='$_POST[id]'");

  mysqli_close($con);

  header("location:myReviews.php");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP, inject the id of the current record into each button, like so:

```
<input type='button' value='Update' onclick='showDiv(" . $row['id'] . ")'/>
```

I am assuming your record is is stored in $row['id'], but you adjust for this as needed.
In your "showDiv" javascript method, create a parameter in the function signature that captures this passed in value. It might look something like this:

```
function showDiv(recId) {
    //recId is my record id, I can use it now!
    //....more javascript here that does stuff

    //access the input element that you want to put the record id into
    var recordIdElement = document.getElementById("recId");

    //finally, update its value to this new recId that was passed in
    recordIdElement.value = recId;
}
```

You will need to pass this value into your id element. Add an id attribute to your input:

```
<input id="recId" type="text" name="id" value="" readonly>
```

If you truly want it to be a hidden element, don't use 'type="text"'. Instead, use 'type="hidden"'.

You will end up with this:

```
<input id="recId" type="hidden" name="id" />
```

Comment: Your a life saver! Thank you so much. But I have to think, why I couldn't think of this.....